# OpenCv facial recognition app detection problem

Tags: python

This is a facial recognition app I had created using python , opencv and haar cascade classifier, the app is working good in classifying trained persons, however the app has a problem of detecting unknown persons as a known person who is trained previously , How to fix such problem ?

```
this is the dataset creation code 



    import cv2
    import os
    import time
    
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    cam.set(3, 640) # set video width
    cam.set(4, 480) # set video height
    
    face_detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier('Cascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
    
    # For each person, enter one numeric face id
    face_id = input('\n enter user id end press <return> ==>  ')
    
    print("\n [INFO] Initializing face capture. Look the camera and wait ...")
    # Initialize individual sampling face count
    count = 0
    
    while(True):
    
        ret, img = cam.read()
        img = cv2.flip(img, 1) 
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        faces = face_detector.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
        width_d, height_d = 150, 150 
        for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (255,0,0), 2)     
            count += 1
    
            # Save the captured image into the datasets folder
            cv2.imwrite("dataset/User." + str(face_id) + '.' + str(count) + ".jpg", cv2.resize(gray[y:y+h,x:x+w] ,  (width_d, height_d)))
            
            cv2.imshow('image', img)
    
        k = cv2.waitKey(100) & 0xff # Press 'ESC' for exiting video
        if k == 27:
            break
        elif count >= 400: # Take 30 face sample and stop video
            
            break
    
    # Do a bit of cleanup
    print("\n [INFO] Exiting Program and cleanup stuff")
    cam.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is the training phase

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import os

# Path for face image database
path = 'dataset'

recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier("Cascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");

# function to get the images and label data
def getImagesAndLabels(path):
    width_d, height_d = 150, 150  # Declare your own width and height

    imagePaths = [os.path.join(path,f) for f in os.listdir(path)]     
    faceSamples=[]
    ids = []

    for imagePath in imagePaths:

        PIL_img = Image.open(imagePath).convert('L') # convert it to grayscale
        img_numpy = np.array(PIL_img,'uint8')

        id = int(os.path.split(imagePath)[-1].split(".")[1])
        faces = detector.detectMultiScale(img_numpy)

        for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
            faceSamples.append(cv2.resize(img_numpy[y:y+h,x:x+w], (width_d, height_d)))
            ids.append(id)

    return faceSamples,ids

print ("\n [INFO] Training faces. It will take a few seconds. Wait ...")
faces,ids = getImagesAndLabels(path)
recognizer.train(faces, np.array(ids))

# Save the model into trainer/trainer.yml
recognizer.write('trainer/trainer.yml') # recognizer.save() worked on Mac, but not on Pi

# Print the numer of faces trained and end program
print("\n [INFO] {0} faces trained. Exiting Program".format(len(np.unique(ids))))
```

This is the recognizing phase

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os 

recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
recognizer.read('trainer/trainer.yml')
cascadePath = "Cascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascadePath);

font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

#iniciate id counter
id =0
# names related to ids: example ==> Marcelo: id=1,  etc

names = ['Mamdouh Alaa' , 'Dr.Ahmed Seddawy' , 'Dr.Ismail Abdulghaffar']

# Initialize and start realtime video capture
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cam.set(3, 1366) # set video widht
cam.set(4, 768) # set video height[enter image description here][1]

# Define min window size to be recognized as a face
minW = 0.1*cam.get(3)
minH = 0.1*cam.get(4)

while True:

    ret, img =cam.read()
    img = cv2.flip(img, 1) 
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    width_d, height_d = 150, 150 

    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale( 
        gray,
        scaleFactor = 1.2,
        minNeighbors = 5,
        minSize = (int(minW), int(minH)),
       )

    for(x,y,w,h) in faces:

        cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (255,0,0), 2)

        id, confidence = recognizer.predict(cv2.resize(gray[y:y+h,x:x+w], (width_d, height_d)))

        # Check if confidence is less them 100 ==> "0" is perfect match 
        if (confidence < 100) :
            id = names[id]
            
            confidence = "  {0}%".format(round(100 - confidence))
        else:
            id = "unknown person"
            confidence = "  {0}%".format(round(100 - confidence))
        
        cv2.putText(img, str(id), (x+5,y-5), font, 1, (255,255,255), 2)
        cv2.putText(img, str(confidence), (x+5,y+h-5), font, 1, (255,255,0), 1)  
    
    cv2.imshow('IFR',img) 

    k = cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xff # Press 'ESC' for exiting video
    if k == 27:
        break

# Do a bit of cleanup
print("\n [INFO] Exiting Program and cleanup stuff")
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: What is a confidence value for known and unknown person?

Comment: confidence value is the percent of how much is the person appearing in real time matching the trained data, however I am also facing inaccurate confident percentage

Comment: This is not what I meant. Maybe your problem is that you have too high confidence threshold for classifying person. In current situation person will be unknown if confidence is eqal to 100

Comment: yes that's actually true, the problem is that the undefined person should have confidence level exceeding 100 so that he is marked unknown, but however the unknown person appear having always a confidence level less than 100

Comment: So what is the range of values for confidence?

Comment: it changes a lot but I observed that it often does not exceed 60 , however I tried to set the maximum limit of confidence to 60 rather than 100 but it did not work as the confidence some times exceed 60 ,  isn't there any solution that replace the idea of confidence to recognise faces ??

Comment: I don't know this library. I used `face_recognition` and it worked really well.

Comment: face_recognition is awesome, but i was unable to send data for training automatically like what i did here ,  that's why I used this one

Comment: could you show me how you used Face_recognition please sir

Comment: This is my old code. It is really messy but it works
https://www.github.com/KacperPaszkowski/realtime-face-recognition/tree/master/live_face_recognition.py